# Correlate Adjacent Element Vales using HTML Agility Pack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to grab the h2 element that follows the HTML comment with the text "Results", followed by the table element with the class name "stockfeed".

I've figured out how to pull the data I need (*see below*), but I not sure how to pull the 2 elements together at the same time.  I know I can iterate the collections using the same indexer to correlate the values, but this seems error prone since it may be possible for one of my h2 elements to not have a adjacent table element (rare but possible).

**Example HTML markup:**

```
<h1>
    Results Page</h1>
<h2>
    Updated Daily @ 10:00 AM</h2>
<div class='someClass1'>
    <!-- Results -->
    <div class='something'>
    </div>
    <h2 style='display: inline;'>
        <a href='http://www.somesite.com'>Table 1</a>
    </h2>
    <div class='clr'>
    </div>
    <div class='resultBlock'>
        <table class='stockfeed'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Part
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Description
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Stock
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Price
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class='row1' valign='top'>
                    <td>
                        A 1234567890
                    </td>
                    <td class='description'>
                        Part Description
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        1,000,000
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $1.99
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='row1' valign='top'>
                    <td>
                        B 1234567890
                    </td>
                    <td class='description'>
                        Part Description
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        1,000,000
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $1.99
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='row1' valign='top'>
                    <td>
                        C 1234567890
                    </td>
                    <td class='description'>
                        Part Description
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        1,000,000
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $1.99
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Results -->
    <div class='something'>
    </div>
    <h2 style='display: inline;'>
        <a href='http://www.somesite.com'>Table 2</a>
    </h2>
    <div class='clr'>
    </div>
    <div class='resultBlock'>
        <table class='stockfeed'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Part
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Description
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Stock
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Price
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class='row1' valign='top'>
                    <td>
                        A 1234567890
                    </td>
                    <td class='description'>
                        Part Description
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        1,000,000
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $1.99
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='row1' valign='top'>
                    <td>
                        B 1234567890
                    </td>
                    <td class='description'>
                        Part Description
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        1,000,000
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $1.99
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr class='row1' valign='top'>
                    <td>
                        C 1234567890
                    </td>
                    <td class='description'>
                        Part Description
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        1,000,000
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        $1.99
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Current code to parse the values separately:**

```
    HtmlNodeCollection titles = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//comment()[contains(.,'Results')]/following-sibling::h2");
    for (int tit = 0; tit < titles.Count; ++tit)
    {
        // Do Something
    }

    HtmlNodeCollection tables = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@class='stockfeed']");
    for (int tab = 0; tab < tables.Count; ++tab)
    {
        // Do Something
    }
```

Comment: +1 for not using regular expressions. ;)

Comment: Just so it's clear what the goal is, what elements are you trying to get?  You never explicitly said what you were trying to get (though it can be inferred from the code what you _might_ want).

Comment: Jeff, I'm trying to grab the h2 element that follows the comment "<!-- Results -->", followed by the table element with the class "stockfeed".

Comment: @Zachary: I've figured that, but you might want to state that in the question itself.  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I'm reading this correctly, you are trying to get the corresponding tables with each result.

You can use a similar approach you used to get the following `h2` element to get the following `table` element relative to it.

```
var query = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//comment()[contains(.,'Results')]/following-sibling::h2");

foreach (var h2 in query.Cast<HtmlNode>())
{
    var table = h2.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::*/table[@class='stockfeed']");
    // do stuff with h2 and table
}
```

Comment: So you still have access to the entire DOM when you have a filtered collection "e.g. h2.SelectSing(....)" ?

Comment: Yes of course!  Though your queries will be relative to the node you are currently at.

Comment: Knowing this, it really makes HAP very powerful and easy to use...  I can now happily retire all my old string/regex HTML parsers!  Thanks!